# how do I stop a 2013 workflow immediately after i have assigned a task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow2013

I have a requirement where in I have started a workflow. I have assigned a task and now I do not want to wait for task action.

I want the workflow to end just after the task is created. How do I do that in SharePoint 2013 workflow?

I am working on designer 2013

Answer (score 3):

Use Stages. Once you have assigned your task within the workflow, then use the "Transition to Stage" : Go to End of Workflow.

[image]